# not able to console input field value when try to declare it global variable in js

Tags: javascript, html

```
   <input type="text" id='listInput'>
    <button type='button' onclick="addList()">Add</button>

<script>

let input = document.getElementById('listInput').value;

   function addList(){
        console.log(input);
    }
 
</script>
```

Here I'm trying to get listInput value and display it on console.

when I declare listInput as global varibale, nothing displays on console but when I declare listInput inside the function and make it local then I get the listInput value.

But I want to declare listInput as global and not local to console listInput value using only javascript.

Comment: `<Element>.value` returns a string value, not a reference. 
You can just initialize `input` with  `document.getElementById('listInput')` and log `input.value` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign input, the value of the input is empty. You could just try with assigning to input the element and not its value and access the value later on in the code:

```
<script>

let input = document.getElementById('listInput');

function addList(){
   console.log(input.value);
}
 
</script>
```